# SAS PROC GLM in a loop

Tags: sas

I tried to run `PROC GLM` in a loop, because I have many models (different combinations of dependent and independent variables), and it’s very time consuming to run them one by one. But log error indicates `only one MODEL statement allowed` in PROC GLM, so any solutions for this?

my code looks like as below

```
data old;
  input year A1 A2 A3 A4 B C D;
datalines;
2000    22  22  30  37  4   13  14
2000    37  29  31  38  6   16  12
2000    42  29  34  37  3   15  15
2000    28  28  27  35  10  13  15
2000    33  22  37  40  9   12  15
2000    22  29  26  40  3   11  15
2000    37  20  32  40  6   12  13
2001    44  22  33  35  7   20  12
2001    33  20  26  40  6   13  15
2001    32  30  37  35  1   12  13
2001    44  25  31  39  4   20  14
2001    25  30  37  38  4   20  10
2001    43  21  35  38  6   11  10
2001    25  23  34  37  5   17  11
2001    45  30  35  37  1   13  14
2001    48  24  36  39  2   13  15
2001    25  24  35  40  9   16  11
2002    38  26  33  35  2   14  10
2002    29  24  35  36  1   16  13
2002    34  28  32  35  9   16  11
2002    45  26  29  35  9   19  10
2002    26  22  38  35  1   14  12
2002    20  26  26  39  8   17  10
2002    33  20  35  37  9   18  12
;
run;

    %macro regression (in, YLIST,XLIST);
    %local NYLIST;
    %let NYLIST=%sysfunc(countw(&YLIST));

    ods tagsets.ExcelXP path='D:\REG' file='Regression.xls';

    Proc GLM data=&in; class year;    

        %do i=1 %to &NYLIST;
          Model %scan(&YLIST,&i)=%scan(&XLIST,1) %scan(&XLIST,2)/ solution;
          Model %scan(&YLIST,&i)=%scan(&XLIST,1) %scan(&XLIST,2)/ solution;
          Model %scan(&YLIST,&i)=%scan(&XLIST,1) %scan(&XLIST,2)/ solution;
        %end;

        %do i=2 %to &NYLIST;
          Model %scan(&YLIST,&i)=%scan(&XLIST,1) %scan(&XLIST,2) %scan(&XLIST,3)/ solution; 
          Model %scan(&YLIST,&i)=%scan(&XLIST,1) %scan(&XLIST,2) %scan(&XLIST,3)/ solution;
          Model %scan(&YLIST,&i)=%scan(&XLIST,1) %scan(&XLIST,2) %scan(&XLIST,3)/ solution;
        %end;

    run;

    ods tagsets.excelxp close;

    %mend regression;
    options mprint;
    %regression
    (in=old
    ,YLIST= A1 A2 A3 A4
    ,XLIST= B C D);
```

---

```
/*potential solutions*/ 

    %macro regression(data,y,x1,x2,x3);
    proc glm data=&data;
    class year;
    model &y=&x1 &x2 &x3/solution;
    run;
    %mend regression;


    %macro sql (mydataset,y,x1,x2,x3);
    proc sql noprint;

    select cats('%regression(&mydataset,',&y,',',&x1,',',&x2,',',&x3,')')  
    into :calllist separated by ' ' from &mydataset;
    quit;
    &calllist.;

    %mend sql;
    %sql 
    (mydataset=old
    ,y=A1 
    ,X1=B
    ,X2=C
    ,X3=D);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in two steps.  One is a macro that contains one instance of PROC GLM:

```
%macro regression(data,y,x1,x2,x3);
proc glm data=&data;
class year;
model &y &x1 &x2 &x3/solution;
run;
%mend regression;
```

And then call that macro from something else, either a macro with the looping elements, or better, from a dataset that contains your y/x1/x2/x3 as columns (one row per model statement) using `call execute` or `proc sql select into` methods.  For example, with a data set `modeldata` containing the y/x values for your model:

```
proc sql noprint;
select cats('%regression(mydataset,',y,',',x1,',',x2,',',x3,')') into :calllist separated by ' ' from modeldata;
quit;
&calllist.;
```

Or similar.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Is there a way to implicitly define number of `x` arguments in `%macro regression`? My number of `xi` is not always 3 (sometimes it goes up to 10...).

Comment: You could do several things.  You could just pass `x` as a string (it is after all used as a string - all of the arguments separated by a space).  You could pass 10 and pass spaces for any missing ones.  You could pass the total number of arguments and iterate over that list.

Comment: okay...one question, what is the difference of mydataset and modeldata?

Comment: `mydataset` is a placeholder as I was too lazy to scroll up.

Comment: Say the dataset name is `old`. Then I should use `select cats('%regression(old,',y,',',x1,',',x2,',',x3,')') into :calllist separated by ' ' from old;`?  Sorry...

Comment: Hi Joe, as I am not quite familiar with those functions, I tried to begin with the simplest scenario,but it didn't work... please see `potential solutions` in my original post. Thanks a lot!